# mailchimp template doesn't display in outlook

Tags: outlook, html-email, mailchimp

I am using a Mailchimp and their template for our email marketing.  I added the outlook specific CSS code, but it still isn't showing correctly in Outlook.  Any suggestions?
Here is part of the header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org      /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>*|MC:SUBJECT|*</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
        /** Outlook 07, 10 Padding issue: These "newer" versions of     Outlook add some padding around table cells potentially throwing off your perfectly pixeled table.  The issue can cause added space and also throw off borders completely.  Use this fix in your header or inline to safely fix your table woes.

More info: http://www.ianhoar.com/2008/04/29/outlook-2007-borders-and-1px-padding-on-table-cells/
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3392/1px-borders-padding-on-table-cells-in-outlook-07/

H/T @edmelly

Bring inline: No.
**/
table td {border-collapse: collapse !important}

        #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" button      */
        .ReadMsgBody{width:600px;} .ExternalClass{width:600px;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
        .yshortcuts, a .yshortcuts, a .yshortcuts:hover, a .yshortcuts:active, a .yshortcuts:focus{background-color:transparent !important; border:none !important; color:inherit !important;} /* Prevent Yahoo! from styling links */

        /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ RESET STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
        body{margin:0; padding:0;}
        img{border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
        table, td{border-collapse:collapse !important; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;}
        #bodyTable, #bodyCell{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;}
        #bodyCell{padding:10px;}
        .templateContainer{width:600px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry but what exactly is not displayed properly in your email? Try to look at other templates like http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-email-templates. They should give you better idea of reliable structure and css. You NEED to inline your css, its standard for email newsletters - its the only way your going to get a consistent look, especially in gmail!

Comment: It's the right column that appears out of line with the left column.Thanks for the link but they specifically state they aren't optimized for Outlook 2007.  The email shows correctly everywhere but Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 0):

You can streamline your template to a more convenient one but heres my 2c:

I suggest you use a tool like litmus, this will allow you to test the rendering of your marketing emails on any email app/browser/device combo.